# kdb array map - how to apply a function to every element of an array?

Tags: kdb

How does one apply a function to every element of an array in kdb?  For example, to square an array of numbers in various languages:

```
javascript: [1,2,3,4].map(square)          -> [1,4,9,16]
python:     [square(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]] -> [1,4,9,16]
kdb:        {[x] x*x} (1;2;3;4)            -> 1 4 9 16
```

So I thought I'd write another function that takes a date and returns the name of a CSV file for that date:

```
q)gobble:{[x] string[x-1970.01.01],".csv"}
q)gobble .z.d // .z.d == today
"16781.csv"
```

Hurrah.  So now I should be able to apply that function to an array of dates and get an array of strings in response, thought I.  Foolish mortal:

```
q)gobble .z.d + til 5 // .z.d + til 5 == array of 5 days starting today
"16781"
"16782"
"16783"
"16784"
"16785"
"."
"c"
"s"
"v"
```

Obviously squaring in kdb was a special case of some kind, not to be generalised to all functions.  How can I tell KDB to apply an arbitrary function to each date in turn, pretty please?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`each`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/each)

```
q)gobble each .z.d + til 5
   "16782.csv"
   "16783.csv"
   "16784.csv"
   "16785.csv"
   "16786.csv"
```

The square operation worked as `*` can operate on atoms as well as lists

```
q)1 2 3 4 * 1 2 3 4
   1 4 9 16
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the ticket!

Answer (score 4):

**Each** is useful but it's advisable to avoid it where possible as it is usually slow. The slash t below returns the timings for running a function, you can see that gobble2 is faster. Look into adverbs

`q)gobble:{[x] string[x-1970.01.01],".csv"}
q)\t gobble each .z.d + til 300200
221
q)gobble2:{[x] string[x-1970.01.01],\:".csv"}
q)\t gobble2 .z.d + til 300200
76`

Comment: Interesting.  This sounds as if there is a "thinking in kdb" nugget hidden inside that timing.  Why is the one faster?  Thank you for your recommendation re adverbs.  This (link) seems to address adverbs in depth.  I'll read it tonight, if nothing displaces it!  http://www.firstderivatives.com/downloads/q_for_Gods_September_2013.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Other variation (not better than adverb each right)

```
  q) f:{[x] string[((),x)-1970.01.01] cross enlist ".csv"}  / () is used to cover case when x is atom
```

If your function is atomic (which will operate on each item of list)  you don't need to use each (and other loop variation). Many inbuilt Q functions are atomic for ex. 'string' or '*'   function in above function.

In your function you are using comma ',' operator which just appends 2 items (2 lists in your case   string[x-1970.01.01] and ".csv") and not atomic in this context . Hence looping element is required.